# How use many desktops in Angular2

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5

I need for skeleton-code how to use 2 or more desktops in Angular2. I create CMS at https://github.com/telenok/telenok

As example i want to have 2 desktop - first for login&password and second - for standart CRUD operations. When session timeout i want to hide CRUD desktop and show login&password. After auth show CRUD desktop again with the same data, tabs as were on it.

Comment: Please add more detail, what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "2 or more desktops"? Angular runs in the browser. If you make your browser window bigger than one desktop it uses multiple desktops ;-)

Comment: As example i want to have 2 desktop - first for login&password and second - for standart CRUD operations. When session timeout i want to hide CRUD desktop and show login&password. After auth show CRUD desktop again with the same data, tabs as were on it.